# Importable `multiprocessing.Pool` function

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

This is probably simple and I'm just not finding a suitable question.

If I do a stand-alone script with `multiprocessing.Pool` i know I'm supposed to do:

```
def foo(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(n_jobs) as p:
        p.map(foo, list_of_inputs)
```

But if I want to then make it an importable function, I assume `__name__` will no longer be `'__main__'`.  Is it safe to just do:

```
def __foo(x):
    return x**2

def bar(list_of_inputs, n_jobs):
    with Pool(n_jobs) as p:
        out = p.map(__foo, list_of_inputs)
    return out

###################################################

from test.py import bar

baz = bar(mylist, 4)
```

I assume so, since `bar` will only be called in the calling process and then only `foo` will be called in the daughter processes, but I'm just wondering if this is a safe way to do this in general.

Comment: After noodling aorund with this for a while, I can't get anything like the above to work without hanging (and not raising any errors).  Would realy appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code that works fine for me in python3 and python2 (if I don't use the `with` statement for the Pool). In my opinion, this is a safe way to use `multiprocessing` and I don't understand why you experience this kind of *infinite hanging*. What version of Python are you using?