# `multiprocessing.Pool` in stand-alone functions

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Re-asking this with a more specific question as my [last version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140777/importable-multiprocessing-pool-function) got no responses.

I'm trying to make an importable function to do Stationary Wavelet Transforms of a dataframe with a series of (long) time histories.  The actual theory isn't important (and I'm perhaps not even using it quite right), the important part is I'm breaking up the time history into blocks and feeding them to multiple threads using `multiprocessing.Pool`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pywt
from multiprocessing import Pool
import functools

def swt_block(arr, level = 8, wvlt = 'haar'):
    block_length = arr.shape[0]
    if block_length == 2**level:
        d = pywt.swt(arr, wvlt, axis = 0)
    elif block_length < 2**level:
        arr_ = np.pad(arr, 
                      ((0, 2**level - block_length), (0,0)), 
                      'constant', constant_values = 0)
        d = pywt.swt(arr_, wvlt, axis = 0)
    else:
        raise ValueError('block of length ' + str(arr.shape[0]) + ' too large for swt of level ' + str(level))
    out = []
    for lvl in d:
        for coeff in lvl:
            out.append(coeff)
    return np.concatenate(out, axis = -1)[:block_length]


def swt(df, wvlt = 'haar', level = 8, processors = 4):
    block_length = 2**level
    with Pool(processors) as p:
        data = p.map(functools.partial(swt_block, level = level, wvlt = wvlt), 
                     [i.values for _, i in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // block_length)])
    data = np.concatenate(data, axis = 0) 
    header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(range(level)),
                                     [0, 1],
                                     df.columns], 
                                     names = ['level', 'coef', 'channel'])
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(data, index = df.index, columns = header)

    return df_out
```

I have done this in a stand-alone script previously so the code works if the second function is instead just bare code wrapped in `if __name__ == '__main__':`, and indeed works in-script if I add a similar block to the end of the script.  But if I import or even just run the above in an interpreter and then do

```
df_swt = swt(df)
```

Things hang indefinitely. I'm sure it's some sort of guard rail on `multiprocessing` to prevent me from doing something dumb with threads, but I'd really prefer not to have to copy this block of code into a bunch of other scripts. Including other tags in case they're the culprits somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all just to be clear, you are creating multiple ***processes*** and not ***threads***. If you are specifically interested in threads, change your import to: `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool`.

From the `multiprocessing` [introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction):

> multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning ***processes*** using an
>   API similar to the threading module.

From the `multprocessing.dummy` [section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy):

> multiprocessing.dummy replicates the API of multiprocessing but is no
>   more than a wrapper around the *threading* module.

Now, I was able to recreate your issue (according to your previous linked question) and indeed the same happened. Running on an interactive shell things simply hanged.

**However**, interestingly enough, running through the windows *cmd*, an endless chain of this error appeared on screen:

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

So, as a wild guess, I added to the **importing** module:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

And......... it worked!

Just to clear the doubt I will post here the exact files I used so you can (hopefully) recreate the solution...

In `multi.py`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def __foo(x):
    return x**2

def bar(list_of_inputs):
    with Pool() as p:
        out = p.map(__foo, list_of_inputs)
    print(out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar(list(range(50)))
```

In `tests.py`:

```py
from multi import bar

l = list(range(50))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar(l)
```

Output when running any of those 2 files (both in shell and through cmd):

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 2116, 2209, 2304, 2401]
```

---

**UPDATE:** I couldn't find any concrete evidence in the docs as to **why** this issue happens, BUT, apparently it has something to do with creating new processes and the [importing of the main module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods).

As discussed in the start of this answer, it seems you meant to use threads in your intensions and didn't know you were using processes. If that is indeed the case, then using actual threads will solve your problem and will not require you to change anything except the import statement (change to: `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool`). With threads you have no restriction on defining the `if __name__ == "__main__":` neither in the main module nor the importing one. So that should work:

In `multi.py`:

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def __foo(x):
    return x**2

def bar(list_of_inputs):
    with Pool() as p:
        out = p.map(__foo, list_of_inputs)
    print(out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar(list(range(50)))
```

In `tests.py`:

```py
from multi import bar

l = list(range(50))

bar(l)
```

I really hope this helps you solve your issue, please let me know if it does.

Comment: So . . . any time I call that function I need to wrap it in `if __name__ == '__main__':`?  I know there are, for example, functions in `sklearn` that use multiple processors but don't require that.

Comment: To tell you the truth I didn't dig in the docs to find the exact cause. I did play around with it and try to put the call to the `Pool` function inside another function but still only wrapping with `__name__`... solved it

Comment: SO, did it help at all or as now you need to add in all modules the `if` it's still a problem?

Comment: It's helpful, but I'd really want to not need the wrapper if possible, as I'd want to deploy it so that other non-experts can use and forcing the wrapper would likely just lead to a ton of problems when other folks use it.

Comment: I try to find some evidence in the docs as to find a solution for this. Closest I got was [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods), under *Safe importing of main module* but there is nothing there suggesting the regular way is wrong...

Comment: So, @DanielF please read my update in the answer and see if that helps you

Comment: There's another [note in this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers).  On Windows, the spawned children need to import your module, so the program entry point needs to be protected with `if __name__ == '__main__':` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405397/python-multiprocessing-continuously-spawns-pythonw-exe-processes-without-doing-a

Comment: @ZachThompson if you know about this, could you elaborate more as this is very confusing? Anyway according to this, assuming OP uses windows, the threads will be the best to avoid restrictions on the users

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't know much more about it but I'll use `multi.py` in your answer to explain what I meant.  On Windows, `Pool.map` needs to re-import `multi.py` for each child process that is spawned.  Without the `if __name__ ...` block, each import will run `bar(list(range(50)))` again, which creates an infinite loop.  With the `if __name__ ...` check, the import safely gets the `__foo` function that `Pool.map` needs, without running the entry-point code again.  On other systems, `os.fork()` is used to avoid the problem as the spawned process will already have `__foo` without another import.

Comment: So in that case, when running (in my example) the `tests.py` it is now the `__main__` module so the child processes will re-import this now and again the same problem of the infinite loop so this is why it also needs the `if __name__...` protection? @ZachThompson

Comment: @Tomerikoo Based on my limitied knowedge, I think `tests.py` would also be problematic on Windows.  I don't have a Windows system to test on, though.  Sorry if I'm only adding to the confusion..  I'm just going on general info I've gleaned from the docs I've found.  I'll post back if I find anything better.

Comment: I don't experience this kind of problem on Linux. Seems to be something with Windows and how it manages the multiprocessing...

Comment: De facto, Windows starts its sub-processes using the "spawn" method whereas Linux uses the "fork" method. When manually choosing the "spawn" method I have the same problem (but the errors are a lot more versatile on Linux).